# Button submit in React results in 404

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-hosting

I have a React app, hosted using Firebase, routing via a `Router` component. No problems when hosting locally via npm.

While accessing via the Firebase URL though, I get a 404 page on clicking a button that has a function attached to it / submitting a form.

```
handleSubmit() {
    console.log("HandleSubmit")
    this.ref.push(this.input.value);
}
```

within `render()`:

```
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Task" ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
            <button type="submit"> Add Task </button>
        </form>
```

Update: in the constructor:

```
this.ref = firebase.database().ref(id + '/tasks');
```

I set up the app as a Single Page app, which got rid of any other 404 issues I previously had:

```
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Not sure where the problem lies. On the locally hosted version clicking the button simply refreshes the page it is on (which is not `index.html`).

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish here this.ref.push(this.input.value); ?

Comment: Where is your app hosted? Do you need to add this location to Authorised domains under Firebase Authentication?

Comment: `this.ref.push` pushes new values to a Firebase database (which works as intended).
App is hosted on Firebase at the default url.